# Angular Js 2 not loading the jquery query builder internal script files

Tags: jquery, angular, query-builder

My Requirement

Need to load the jquery query builder inside a modal using the angularjs 2 typescript

What I have done

I have created a dynamic forms in angularjs 2 which contains 3 select box and 1 text box, in the text box on-click of that am I have called the bootstrap modal inside the modal body I have coded the query builder and created a internal java script for that query builder inside the template_rule.html

Whats happening

when I click the text box modal pop up is happening and inside the modal body only three buttons are rendering and the main query builder view in not rendering.

this is the fully working demo link(http://plnkr.co/edit/d38iwjLhJzTjM5t46zD7?p=preview)

Demo Link Functionality

in this link there will be a button in top left corner click that it will keep on adding a set of fields, in that set of fields there will be a text box if you click that text box a modal will pop up, in that only am rendering the query builder, the buttons will be showing but the core functionality part is not showing in that modal pop up, the query builder script is in app/template_rule.html file and the necessary libraries are included in index.html file, please help me to resolve this

this is a part of code for full working code please refer the link above

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {
        FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, ControlArray, Validators, NgForm, Control,
            AbstractControl
    }from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl:'app/template_rule.html',
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
userForm: ControlGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
this.userForm = fb.group({
  rules_list:  new ControlArray([])
    });
    this.rules_list();
 }

 rules_list(){
    this.userForm.controls['rules_list'].push(this.fb.group({
        select_state: this.fb.control("",Validators.required),
        rules: this.fb.control("", Validators.required),
        pass_state: this.fb.control("", Validators.required),
        fail_state: this.fb.control("", Validators.required)
    }));
}

removeRules(ctrl) {
     let rulesLists = (<Array>(<ControlGroup>this.userForm.controls['rules_list']).controls);
    for(var i = 0; i < rulesLists.length; i++) {
         console.log("each rules", ctrl);
        if(rulesLists[i] == ctrl) {
         console.log("rules to remove", rulesLists[i]);
            rulesLists.splice(i, 1);
            (<ControlGroup>this.userForm.controls['rules_list']).updateValueAndValidity();
         break;
        }
    }
}

submitRules() {
     console.log(this.userForm.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by loading the query builder script file dynamically in angular 2 when the template loads

below are the code to load dynamically

```
load_script(){
var head=document.getElementByTagName('head')[0];
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src='js file url'
head.appendChild(script);
}
```